# Review your recently-rejected edits lands on user's homepage

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Whenever I try to edit a question or an answer, I get this message at the top of the page:

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> **Warning!** Some of your previous edits were rejected. Please [review your recently-rejected edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) before continuing. Too many rejected edits may cause your editing privileges to be suspended.

But that link sends me to my profile page where I can't find any suggested edits history. Is that link incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this seems to be an error.

The correct URL should be:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=allactions&sort=suggestions

This is probably a consequence of the recent changes to the user page and layout. The link probably worked in the old layout, but hasn't been updated to the new layout (`tab=activity` instead of `tab=allactions`).

Until this is fixed, you can just follow the link, select the "all actions" tab and then the "suggestions" tab below it.